# How do I delete an angular $scope variable correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to delete a $scope variable in my controller, how can I do this?

```
$scope.myVar = ";
```

This doesn't remove the variable. I want to completely remove it from the $scope. What is the best way to do this performance wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete $scope.myVar;
```

See the `delete` operator ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete